# Passing firebase data from one activty to another, onClick of ListView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having some trouble passing data from one activity to another, onItem click I want to pass the value of the item clicked to another activity, in the following code it only the final piece of data  as opposed to the item clicked, any help greatly appreciated.

```
            public class list_view extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

    final String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("ProgressReports").child(uid);
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
    final Context context = this;
    EditText searchBarProgress = findViewById(R.id.searchBarProgress);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    String key = uidRef.push().getKey();
    ReportInformation report = new ReportInformation();
    report.setTitle("title");
    report.setContent("content");
    report.setKey(key);
    uidRef.child(key).setValue(report);


    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                id.add(ds.getKey());
                String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                String content = ds.child("content").getValue(String.class);
                String timestamp = ds.child("timestamp").getValue(String.class);
                list.add(title + "\n" + timestamp + "\n" + content);
                Log.d("TAG", title);
            }
            ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.progressList);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

    final ListView progressList = findViewById(R.id.progressList);

    progressList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int x, long l) {

            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    ArrayList<ReportInformation> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        ReportInformation report = ds.getValue(ReportInformation.class);
                        list.add(report);
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(list_view.this, ProgressReports.class);
                    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.progressList);
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                        }
                    });
                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            };
            uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    });
```

To show what I mean, regardless of which button I press in the following listview, the data passed over is Test 4

[image: ListView]

[image: Test 4 passed over]

Below is my firebase structure

[image: Firebase structure]

Model class for objects

```
public class ReportInformation {
private String title;
private String content;
private String timestamp;
private String key;

public ReportInformation(){

}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
}
```

Getting the following error when trying to do that

[image: Error]

New error
[image: new error]

[image: Error adding to list]

Comment: Do you have a model class for your objects?

Comment: Hi Alex, yes uploaded it there, trying to implement what you've said
[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560566/passing-firebase-data-from-one-activty-to-another-onclick-of-listview?noredirect=1#comment93987695_53560566 

but struggling when it comes to where to place intents etc

I've also uploaded what ive done so far in implementing your method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you need first to implement `Serializable` interface like this:

```
ReportInformation implements Serializable {}
```

So to pass your entire `ReportInformation` object to the next activity, you should use the following lines of code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        ReportInformation reportInformation = arrayAdapter.getItem(i);
        Intent intent = new Intent(list_view.this, ProgressReports.class);
        intent.putExtra("object", reportInformation);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Getting an error when trying to implement this, stuck a screen shot up

Comment: To solve that error, please change the type of your `ArrayAdaper` from String to `ReportInformation`. Should be `ArrayAdaper<ReportInformation>`. Does it work now?

Comment: Hey Alex, I feel we're close and I can't thank you enough for your help so far, but ran into this error when changing the ReportInformation (Uploaded)

Probably me overcomplicating things form the start

Comment: Change the type of your list also to `ReportInformation`. `List<ReportInformation>`.

Comment: That resolved that issue, but opened a new issue when trying to add the data to the list initially, apologies for all the hassle

Comment: The fact that you get another issue, it means that the initial **errors** disappeared and this are good news :) but this sounds as a new problem which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. As a personal guess, I think that is something related with the list but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you and don't forget to accept both answers that helped you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Alex ill add this up now

Comment: Please send me the link once you add the new question to see how I can help you.

Comment: I just need to wait until the question has been posted for 90 minutes, hopefully an easy fix, but I doubt it lol

Comment: Yes, you're new. You should wait that time and post the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53562015/passing-firebase-data-from-one-activity-to-another-via-clickable-listview

Thanks again Alex